# Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError in the sidenav angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-sidenav

I have the next code:

```
 <mat-sidenav #sidenav                 
                 [fixedInViewport]="false"
                 [opened]="opened"
                 mode="side"
                 fxFlex="none"
                 [style.position]="sidenav.mode !== 'push' && sidenav.opened  ? 'relative' : 'absolute'"
                 style="width: 25rem;"
                  >
```

The error happens with this expression:  `[style.position]="sidenav.mode !== 'push' && sidenav.opened  ? 'relative' : 'absolute'"`:

Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'absolute'. Current value: 'relative'.

The error doesn't happen if I put `opened` but then, I can't close the menu by default in responsive.

The link in stackblitz is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9nhmdw?file=src/app/app.module.ts)

Comment: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/ I find this article really good in debugging this issue.

Comment: Can you send a link to a repo or stackblitz where the error occurs? Because I cannot reproduce it

Comment: @officialMKL here is the link:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9nhmdw?file=src/app/app.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

In your example I have removed `sidenav.opened` from the expression and then the error isn't appearing. The Sidenav is also closing and opening as expected in differnt resolutions.

Comment: I need to review my application because when I remove sidenav.opened the function push of sidenav doesn't work well.  The content is placed under the sidenav.